# What is the most efficient way to get Active Directory properties for current user in ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, .net-3.5, asmx, asp.net-3.5

Have ASP.NET 3.5 web application (pages/services) running.  They are configured to impersonate using windows authentication.  What is the most efficient (quickest) way to get the 3-4 properties from Active Directory for the current user? Most efficient could be the fastest synchronous or an async model that would work.

Note: I am aware of aware of using the DirectorySearcher, however, was wondering if there was a more efficient way since I already have the user context (by way of impersonation).

TIA!!

Comment: Can you define efficient. Least code? Least execution time? Least memory used? Least network bandwidth used?

Answer (score 0):

With impersonation you can get the users domain and samaccountname. As far as I know, you still would need to use a directory searcher against the samaccountname to lookup the properties - (&(objectcategory=person)(samaccountname=x))